# react router 6.4.3 nested routes with two different routes pointing to one route/component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Greeting,

I am make a website to display different products.
Assume I have the following routes:

```
perfume/a-specific-perfume
base/a-specific-base
```

These routes both display a single page with a single product, which is nice, but what if I have many different type of product. This would lead me to have the following routes:

```
perfume/a-specific-perfume
base/a-specific-base
water/...
.../...
```

It leads to repetitive works for each type of product.

Is there a way to ignore the root route? I tried using a wild card, `"*/a-specific-perfume"` or `"*/p/a-specific-perfume"`, and it did not work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the wildcard character `"*"` is only valid at the end of a path and only serves to indicate that a route component can render descendent routes. You can use route path params for dynamic path segments.

Examples:

```
<Route path="/:type/a-specific-perfume" element={....} />
<Route path="/:type/a-specific-base" element={....} />
<Route path="/foo/:type/a-specific-perfume" element={....} />
<Route path="/bar/:type/a-specific-base" element={....} />
```

In each component (*the `element` prop*) use the `useParams` hook to access the route param value.

> ```
> "/perfume/a-specific-perfume"
> "/base/a-specific-base"
> "/water/..."
> "/.../..."
> ```

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { type } = useParams(); // "perfume"|"base"|"water"|"..."|etc...
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot you could put dynamic path in the back like "/:type/a-specific-perfume". I think double dynamic paths is what I needed like "/:type/:something". I did not make the question clearly, sorry.

Comment: @jackychulo Nothing to apologize for, I thought your question was clear enough to understand the issue, and provide explanation and proposed solution. Cheers and good luck.